# firefox: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

After upgrading `firefox` and `selenium` I experience some issues with some code

I'm not very experienced with `python`

## code

```
import sys
import time
import getopt
import urllib
import selenium
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Scrape:
    display = None
    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        #   Start display
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()

        #   Init args
        query = ''
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['query=','proxy='])
            for opt, arg in opts:
                if opt == '--query':
                    query = arg
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            self.error(str(err))

        #   Init driver
        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException as err:
            self.error(str(err))
        print('teeeesting...!')

    def error(self, str):
        self.close()

        print>>sys.stderr, str
        sys.exit(1)

    def close(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.display.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Scrape()
```

## error

```
# python selenium_scrape.py --query "test"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_scrape.py", line 48, in <module>
    Scrape()
  File "selenium_scrape.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.error(str(err))
  File "selenium_scrape.py", line 38, in error
    self.close()
  File "selenium_scrape.py", line 44, in close
    self.driver.quit()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  For instance, does reproducing the problem *really* depend on *all* of those `import` statements?

Comment: Suggestion: `print>>sys.stderr, str` *before* `self.close()`, so that you can see the diagnostic message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events seems to be:

1. You ran into an exception while scraping; your driver was not properly initialized.
2. The exception handler called `error`.
3. `error` called `close`.
4. `close` *tried* to call `quit`, but `self` (your driver) has a value of `None` ... which has no method named `quit`.

Hence the final error trace-back.  Insert a couple of strategic `print` commands to trace whether your driver ever got initialized (I expect not).  A likely spot would be in the exception handler under `Init driver`: print the exception you raised, and perhaps one or two useful values surrounding the problem.